# What is an (x,y) plot alternative to matplotlib in Python?

Tags: python, graphing

I've been trying for several hours to download/build/install/use [`matplotlib`](http://matplotlib.org/) and am at my wit's end. I finally got it to build and it runs but doesn't display anything despite calling `plt.show()`.

Is there an alternative to matplotlib? I just need something in Python to graph (x,y) data, in either lines or points. (I'm running Python 2.7 in Mac OSX 10.6)

**edit:** *please* point me at a source of binary installers for any reputable package besides matplotlib. Building from source code on my machine seem to have trouble for some reason.

Comment: I'm beginning to think matplotlib is some giant hoax :/

Comment: I second this. Matplotlib's build environment just doesn't seem to work well. I've already spent hours trying to make it work on a linux cluster without internet access. First the dependencies weren't well documented, then I have to edit .h files just to make it compile, then I get linker errors because for some reason the gcc linker flags weren't set up correctly. With g++ there's a different set of linker errors. It may have to do with the fact that the cluster runs on SUSE linux which isn't the most common - on the other hand most other linux software handles this just fine.

Comment: Didn't I hear about a ggplot for Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since posting this question I found out about the free [Anaconda Python](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/) which has precompiled binaries for the major platforms, and includes matplotlib, so I've been using that.

Answer (score 1):

Even the .dmg files don't install, say, from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/matplotlib/files/matplotlib/matplotlib-1.1.0/)?

There are other options though.  There's Chaco, gnuplot, and you can call R from Python, etc.

Comment: the sourceforge binaries are for OSX 10.3, 10.4, and 10.5; 10.6 and 10.7 are 64-bit OS's and are not compatible. >:(

Comment: ...and I just tried `sudo port gnuplot` which took the better part of an hour only to fail towards the end. sigh. :-(

Comment: Really, dmg won't work? I'm running OSX 10.6 and am quite sure I installed matplotlib from one of the official matplotlib dmgs, though it was awhile ago and I'm not 100% sure where I got the dmg.  (All my notes say is, "I couldn't install matplotlib successfully with either pip or easy_install, so I used the .dmg file")

Comment: Nope, I get `ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so, 2): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_path.so: no matching architecture in universal wrapper`

Comment: ...but that's not the point. I'm looking for something that installs easily on other systems; even if I get it to work, I need to give my python scripts to someone else & there's no way they'll have as much patience as I do trying to get it to work.

Comment: The issue is almost certainly at 64/32 bit issue, and you're running Python in 64 bit but matplotlib only has a 32 bit dmg version.  You can probably get yours running by starting Python with a command like python2.7-32 and see how that goes.  If you want to completely avoid this issue, I don't know any "binary installers" for plotting packages that have a 64-bit version, but you could instead go for a pure python plotting package, like PyChart, http://home.gna.org/pychart/ .

Comment: Also, I generally find setting up a whole environment, with a bunch of different packages, etc, to be some effort.  Whether this is Python, Eclipse, VC++, etc, it's always a hassle.  If a client needs this, I do it for them.  Other solutions are to put things in a self-contained and self-consistent bundle using something like, py2app, etc, and then they just click and go; or you could do an installer (I've no experience here).  It seems to me though, if you're expecting someone to install multiple packages, making a note of the 64/32 bit problem will be the least of your worries.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [PyCha](https://bitbucket.org/lgs/pycha/wiki/Home) or [pyCairoChart](http://launchpad.net/pycairochart) if you are looking for simple Matplotlib alternatives. They are of course not as mature or versatile as Matplotlib is, but they might be enough for you.

Comment: The link for the pyCairoChart is broken. Here is an existing one: https://launchpad.net/pycairochart

Answer (score 1):

If you *just* need to plot points and lines, you could use Tkinter (which is probably already installed) and use a canvas widget. It's pretty much what it sounds like: a blank canvas with primitives for drawing lines, points, etc.

Answer (score 0):

First, matplotlib should be installable and most python plattforms, it has become a de-facto standard for plotting with python. I'm sad to read that you are struggling with the installation.

Second, you could have a look at [ScientificPython](http://dirac.cnrs-orleans.fr/plone/software/scientificpython/) (not to confuse with scipy). It has a simple TkPlotCanvas, providing some abstraction around the TkInter canvas widget. Maybe you can find a way to incorporate the relevant parts into you project. The license is CeCILL, yet another open-source variant. I don't know about your project and its license, but this could lead to seamless integration of plotting, without external dependencies.

Comment: The problem is that matplotlib now requires Python3.6, and a default install for 3.6 is not readily available in Ubuntu 16.04. It requires doing some complicated workarounds to get matplotlib working. There's always Anaconda though.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Charts](https://github.com/arnoutaertgeerts/python-highcharts) library which enables you to make plots in Python using the excellent javascript [Highcharts](http://highcharts.com) library.

The library is mainly HTML/Javascript and **only uses python standard libraries** so it installs easily on any platform. Compared to matplotlib it offers almost all of their features and is able to make **interactive** charts!

*Disclaimer: I'm the developper of the library.*